# Identify the formula for the following graph

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for a formula to describe the following the graph below:

range : [0,1]

domain: [0,infinite)

[image]

The formula should be in f(x) = y form, and it should curve from 0 to 1 (doesn't need to be harmonized).

I was thinking of using upper-half ellipse formula, but I couldn't keep the y value from going down, and then I tried using euler, but it turns out to be more complicated that I thought...

Any helps is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$, or something like that.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x+1}+1$, $f(x)=\frac{-1}{2^x}+1$ looks like it.

Comment: You may find a collection of such half-sigmoids at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (the picture at the bottom right).

Comment: Thanks, all, for the solutions. I found @Sawarnik 's solution -- f(x)=1-1/(x+1) -- to be the easiest one to calculate and apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one function that satisfies this.

$$f(x)=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-1}{e-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use $1-e^{-x}$. That is pretty simple.